# Guarantee of sameness of output after switching order in functional programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I started reading some of Haskell's documentation, and there's a fundamental concept I just don't understand. I read about it in other places as well, but I want to understand it once and for all.

In many places discussing functional programing, I keep reading that if the functions you're using are pure (have no side effects, and give same response for the same input at every call) then you can switch the order in which they are called when composing them, with it being guaranteed that the output of this composed call will remain the same regardless of the order.

For example, here is [an entry from the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside):

> Haskell is a pure language, which means that the result of any
>   function call is fully determined by its arguments. Pseudo-functions
>   like rand() or getchar() in C, which return different results on each
>   call, are simply impossible to write in Haskell. Moreover, Haskell
>   functions can't have side effects, which means that they can't effect
>   any changes to the "real world", like changing files, writing to the
>   screen, printing, sending data over the network, and so on. These two
>   restrictions together mean that any function call can be replaced by
>   the result of a previous call with the same parameters, and the
>   language guarantees that all these rearrangements will not change the
>   program result!

But when I fiddle with this idea I can quickly think of examples that contradict the statement above. For instance, let's say I have two functions (I will use pseudo code rather than Haskell):

```
x(a)->a+3

y(a)->a*3


z(a)->x(y(a))

w(a)->y(x(a))
```

Now, if we execute `z` and `w`, we get:

```
z(5) //gives 3*5+3=18

w(5) //gives (5+3)*3=24
```

That being so, I think I misunderstood the promised guarantee they speak about. Can anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 8):

When you compare `x(y(a))` to `y(x(a))`, those two expressions are not equivalent because `x` and `y` aren't called with the same arguments in each. In the first expression `x` is called with the argument `y(a)` and `y` is called with the argument `a`. Whereas in the second `y` is called with `x(a)`, not `a`, as its argument and `x` is called with `a`, not `y(a)`. So: different arguments, (possibly) different results.

When people say that the order does not matter, they mean that in the following code:

```
a = f(x)
b = g(y)
```

you can switch the definition of `a` and `b` without affecting their values. That is it makes no difference whether `f` is called before `g` or vice versa. This is clearly not true for the following code:

```
a = getchar()
b = getchar()
```

If you switch `a` and `b` here, their values are switched as well, because `getchar` returns a (possibly) different character each time that it's called. So a purely functional language can't have a function exactly like `getchar`.

Comment: thanks, i guess i just took their guarantee to the extreme :)